# Find the same written number from input in the option (in form) javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello to everyone i need get the number which someone can write in input and than show the option with the same number

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");  
btn.addEventListener("click", funct);
    
function funct(){  
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");   
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
  var options = select.options; 
  for( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ){
    options[i].selected = input.value; 
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option> 
</select> <br> <br> 
<input type="text" id="myInput"> <br> <br> 
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
```

Comment: <select id="mySelect">

  <option>one</option>

  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<br>
<br>
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is clear out any `selected` attributes that may have previously been set and set `selected` on the `option` with an index that is supplied by the user as long as that input is a valid index for the `select`.

And, since indexes are always numbers, it makes sense to use `input type='number'` so that only numeric data can be entered in the first place.

```js
// Get your DOM references just once, not every time the button is clicked:
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");   
var select = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");  

btn.addEventListener("click", funct);
    
function funct(){  
  // If the user's input is within the range of select indexes
  if(input.value >= 0 && input.value < select.options.length){

    // Loop over all the options and remove any previously selected ones
    for( var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++ ){
      select.options[i].selected = false;
    }
    
    // Select the option that matches the user's input for an index
    select.options[input.value].selected = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="">Make a Selection</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option> 
</select> <br> <br> 
<input type="number" min="0" id="myInput"> <br> <br> 
<button id="myBtn">Button</button>
```

Comment: @Marie It works based on what you described. If you type `one` in the textbox and click the button, `one` will be selected in the drop down. That's what I interpreted your question to be asking.

Comment: Look, i write the number for example 1 javascript should check in the option find option[1] and select it

Comment: @Marie Oh, that wasn not clear. Let me adjust the code.

Comment: ok) thank you but i want to find something without setattribute

Comment: @Marie Answer updated again. But, in the future, please state all of this in your question.

Comment: thank you) hope you understand that i am new here)))

Comment: @Marie You're welcome, but being clear is always a good idea. ;)